# can I initialize an array in the parameter of a constructor

Tags: java

I am writing two constructors of a class Triangle which takes as parameters : a String , an integer  and a double array

```
private double [] side = new double[3];

public Triangle() {
    this("",0,side);
//Here I have a compile error says "Cannot refer to an instance field side while explicitly invoking a constructor"
}

public Triangle(String color, int opacity,double [] side) {
    super(color, opacity);
    this.side = side ;
}
```

in the main method i wanted to initialize the triangle
 but I was not able to do so till now ..

i tried these two ways but non of them worked

```
    GeoShapes[1] = new Triangle( "Red"  , 89 , {2,4,3} ) ;

    GeoShapes[2] = new Triangle( "white", 68 , new double{5,6,3} );
```

note :
I did try initialize an array then putting its reference in the third parameter 
and it works , but this not what I need

could any one help what should I write in the third parameter ?

Comment: You're not defining an array, you're trying to create a double with multiple initial values. You have to add `[]`.

Comment: Why do you need the array as a local variable *and* an argument to the superclass constructor? That suggests you'll end up with the same value in two places, which is a design smell.

Comment: @JonSkeet. Sorry but I didn't understand which part of the code you are referring to.

Comment: @JonSkeet  neither me ! :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant *instance* variable and an argument to the superclass constructor. I suspect the superclass constructor is already going to store this in an instance variable in the superclass.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use it like this:

```
geoShapes[1] = new Triangle("Red"  , 89 , new double[] {2,4,3});
```

You can use the array initializers only at the point of declaration, or with array creation expression.

Another option is to use `varargs` as parameter type:

```
public Triangle(String color, int opacity, double... side) {
    super(color, opacity);
    this.side = side ;
}
```

then you can create instance using:

```
geoShapes[1] = new Triangle("Red", 89 , 2, 4, 3);
```

---

Regarding the issue in your 0-arg constructor:

```
public Triangle() {
    this("",0,side);
}
```

you're trying to pass the instance field `side` to the parameterized constructor, which isn't valid, because `side` hasn't been initialized yet. All the initialization are done after `this()` or `super()` invocation. You should create an array and pass it like you would do normally. So this would work:

```
public Triangle() {
    this("", 0, new double[] {0, 0, 0});
}
```

---

And please follow proper Java naming conventions. Variable names start with lowercase alphabets.

Comment: thanks  Rohit Jain , that works , but why this one doe not work   GeoShapes[1] = new Triangle( "Red"  , 89 , {2,4,3} ) ;

Comment: @jShaalan. Because compiler cannot infer the actual type of array you intended to pass.

Comment: And then the declaration of side should just be `private double[] side;`.

Comment: @iShaalan That is an instance member. Not a class member to  ready avail.

Comment: please follow proper Java naming conventions. Variable names start with lowercase alphabets.   ++ you meant " GeometricShapes " ,Am i right ?

Comment: @iShaalan Yes. That should be `geometricShapes` or `geoShapes`.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
private double [] side = new double[3];

public Test() {
    this("",0,side);
//Here I have a compile error says "Cannot refer to an instance field side while explicitly invoking a constructor"
}
```

You can't use `side` because the constructor hasn't really been called yet and therefore instance variables haven't been initialized. This is explained in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1)

> An **explicit constructor invocation statement in a constructor body** may
>   not refer to any instance variables or instance methods or inner
>   classes declared in this class or any superclass, or use this or super
>   in any expression; otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

The **bold** part is referring to the `this()` call.

One option is to pass a new array.

```
public Test() {
    this("",0, new double[3]);
}
```

You don't need to initialize the `side` field because both your constructors do it.

For the other beef, check the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing bracket in both the cases and also `new` to create an array:

```
new Triangle( "Red"  , 89 , {2,4,3};
```

should be

```
new Triangle( "Red"  , 89 , new double[]{2,4,3});
```

Comment: Sorry , i just fixed that